# Drawing multiple "many-to-many" entities in a E-R model

Tags: database-design, relational-database, visio

In an E-R Diagram how would i model two many-to-many relationships

```
 FACILITY
 Facility_ID
 Name
 etc

 PHYSICIAN
 Physician_Id
 Name
 etc

 PATIENT
 Patient_Id
 Name
 etc
```

M:N - where a Facility can staff many Physicians and a Physician can be enmployed by many facilities
M-N - where a Patient can be treated by many Physicians and a Physicians can treat many patients'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common relational design problem. To solve it, you create so called a junction table or an associative entity.

Here are some helpful explanations with examples that should help you relate to yours:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

In your case, you would probably have:

```
 Facilty_Physican
 ----------------
 Facility_ID
 Physician_Id
```

and

```
 Physican_Patient
 ----------------
 Physician_Id
 Patient_Id
```

You may also find that sometimes in data model optimizations and depending on the balance of the relationship some denormalize junction tables.

Answer (score 1):

Modelling many-to-many relations is done by making a table in between the two relevant tables and hereby dividing tit into two one-to-many-relations. Thus: a Facility_Physician table which has two columns that are both foreign_keys. The first FK references Facility_ID and the second column references Physician_Id.
The same goes for the Patient_Physician table.